# Registry query information gives incorrect values

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

With the code bellow i have been trying to query value information under a certain registry key. I'm just interested in the amount of values, value name length and value size. But when i run the code it only gives the correct value for number of values. The other values are too long and incorrect. If i lengthen the values it changes, but other than the number of values, the values never gets shorter unless i removes the variables outright.

The code used:

```
HKEY openRegister(HKEY rootKey,const wchar_t* subKey)
{   
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG result=RegOpenKeyEx(rootKey,subKey,0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY,&hKey);

    if(result!=ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if(result==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) 
        {
            cout<<"Key not found"<<endl;            
    } 
        else 
        {
            cout<<"Error opening key"<<endl;            
        }
    }
    
    return hKey;
}

bool infoKey(HKEY regKey,DWORD &numValues,DWORD &maxNameLen,DWORD &maxValueSize)
{
    LONG result=RegQueryInfoKeyA
    (
        regKey,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &numValues,
        &maxNameLen,
        &maxValueSize,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    if(result!=ERROR_SUCCESS)   
    {
        cout<<"Error query info"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Calling openRegister and then infoKey functions, gives this output:

```
Number of values: 2
Max name length: 12
Max value size: 12
```

while looking in the Registry Editor this is the actual content:

```
(default) | REG_SZ | (value not set)
string1   | REG_SZ | Hello
string2b  | REG_SZ | Test
```

Why is the "number of values" only correct?
Am i missing something really obvious?

Thanks in advance, Benji.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lpcbMaxValueLen` parameter outputs the size of the longest data expressed in bytes.  The longest data in your example is `Hello`, which as a Unicode string (the format the Registry internally stores strings in) is 6 characters, counting the null terminator, and so is 12 bytes in size (2 bytes per character).  So `maxValueSize` being set to 12 is accurate.

The `lpcbMaxValueNameLen` parameter outputs the length of the longest name expressed in Unicode characters, not counting the null terminator.  The longest name in your example is `string2b`, which has a length of 8 characters.  So you would expect `maxNameLen` should be getting set to 8, not 12. But apparently there is an undocumented minimum size to name buffers. Why, who knows.

On a side note, you are opening the key using a Unicode function, and then querying its info using an ANSI function.  You should not mix ANSI and Unicode APIs like that.  You should be using `RegQueryInfoKeyW()` instead of `RegQueryInfoKeyA()`, to match your use of `RegOpenKeyExW()` (which `RegOpenKeyEx()` calls, since you are passing it a `wchar_t` string).

Comment: Oooh it has 16-bit characters of course! As to MaxNameLength I am sure i am printing the values correctly so no error there. I had no idea that's what the W/A ending meant! I recently learned that the "Ex" ending means an improved version two of the API, so i thought that W/A was like a version 3 or 4 hehe. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I should also say that now that I'm just isolating maxNameLen, i can see that no matter what values are in the key, maxNameLen is always at least 12, if I make the value name longer, it works as expected. But it never goes below 12.

Comment: I can reproduce this. It is not a problem with the code itself, that is just how the Registry API works. In fact, as a test, I renamed one of the names to 13 characters, and then renamed it back, and `lpcbMaxValueNameLen` started reporting 13 instead of 12. Repeated with 15 characters, similar result. So there is clearly some buffer/cache action going on inside the Registry. `RegQueryInfoKey()` is primary meant for letting you allocate buffers dynamically for subsequent reads/enumerations, so clearly the Registry is trying to be helpful in reporting reasonable sizes, not actual sizes.

Comment: On a side note, `openRegister()` is returning an invalid `HKEY` if `RegOpenKeyEx()` fails, since `hKey` is uninitialized in that case.

Comment: Ok, weird that it can't be lower than 12 though!? I was aware of the HKEY thing, it would print the error if it failed, so i would at least been notified.